# 2014 Kia Sorento power door lock locks all doors but only unlocks driver side door

Tags: kia, central-locking, sorento

A 2014 Kia Sorento where suddenly the power door lock's unlock function has stopped working for all but the driver's door.

- The power unlock function will only unlock the driver's side door. The passenger side front door and both rear doors do not unlock.
- All doors can be manually unlocked.
- Happens with either the FOB or either of the central door lock/unlock buttons on the driver or passenger side front seats (rear seats have no such button).
- The power lock function works correctly on all doors.
- There is no sound from the malfunctioning doors when using the unlock function.
- Problem started all at once.
- There is no mention of a setting to achieve this in the user manual.
- It appears all the door locks run off a single fuse.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I understand what you mean man, I’m having the same issue with my 2014 Kia sorento. It’s not a setting or the key fob and I don’t have the screen that he’s talking about and Kia can’t give me any answers. As many people struggling with this it should be a recall. Anyone find a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a simple configuration issue. Most modern cars have a way of customizing settings such as how long headlight stay on, how doors lock whether only driver door or all 4 doors open etc and so on. If you are configured with the driver only opens remotely. Usually 1 press of the unlock button just opens the driver door. 2 quick pressings of the unlock button should open all the doors. I am not familiar with specifically with KIA but if it anything like Honda or Toyota the way to access configuration settings are by pressing buttons on the left hand side of the steering wheel with one of them labeled Menu and the rest is straightforward after that.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I can find no configuration setting that disables unlocking non-driver's doors.

Answer (score 0):

With due acknowledgement to @Old_Fossil, go to your car's manual, chapter 4, page 70 and see how to control the LCD display so that you can change modes and user settings.

Then see chapter 4, page 78-79 for door settings. Turn off the "Two Press Unlock" function.

[image]

Credit: Kia Motors

Comment: I appreciate the response, but this isn't it. The non-driver's doors do not unlock no matter how many times the unlock function is activated.